# Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm alternatives in Neurolab

Tags: python, neural-network, levenberg-marquardt

I am porting neural network code in Matlab that uses Levenberg-Marquardt training algorithm to Python. I am using Neurolab, which I believe does not come with Levenberg-Marquardt training algorithm. Is there any alternative training algorithm I can use? I am using a feed forward multilayer network. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A new (recurrent) neural network toolbox called [pyrenn](https://pyrenn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) has been released, which exploits the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. I have actually used it myself very recently and got same results as in Matlab.

You can install it using pip.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Levenberg-Marquardt is an optimization method for estimating the parameters for a neural network.  There are many other algorithms (back propagation, quick prop, and many more).  My favorite all text web page is the [Neural Network FAQ](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html), which explains many of these techniques.

However, the end result is a trained neural network.  So, you can try other training techniques available in Neurolab (which I have not used).  Some may perform better than others, but they are all doing the same thing -- setting appropriate parameter values.